# why do i get undefined when i input {} in side a function that get the type of input

Tags: javascript

I made a code that get a type of inputs.All of the inputs that i add to the function have there correct answers (ex:prompt(10) result is : Number). when i tried to add object like this({}) i get Undefined the code that i made is :

```
function type() {
  var Input = eval (prompt("please enter a value"));
  var Primitive = [Boolean(Input), String(Input), null, undefined, 
  Number(Input)];
 for (i = 0; i < Primitive.length; i++) {
    if (Primitive[i]) {
      console.log (typeof Input)
    }
  }
}
type();
```

I tried to use instanceof but i get the same result for object which is undefined.

The Expected result when i prompt {} i get Object.
note: for Array [] i get object no problem in it .

Comment: Try `typeof Primitive[i]` instead

Comment: if you use `eval({})` Javascript will treat {} as an empty block, not an object. I (and many developers) highly disencourage the use of `eval()`

Comment: Please don't use `eval`, especially when the thing you are `eval`ing doesn't need to be `eval`ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use `eval({})` Javascript will treat {} as an empty block, not an object. I (and many developers) highly disencourage the use of `eval()`

you can escape this using `eval("(" + prompt("please enter a value") + ")");`

Here's the difference:

```
var Input = eval (prompt("please enter a value")); 
// if you type {} this will turn into eval({}) wich is the same as eval() which will return "undefined"

Input = eval("(" + prompt("please enter a value") + ")");
//Typing {} will turn into eval(({})) wich makes {} an expression instead of an empty block. thus returning "object"
```

Comment: Me: *enters `0); alert("no"); //`*

Comment: mm, that's true.

Answer (score 0):

`{}` gets interpreted as an (empty) block of code, not an object literal. It has no return value, so it defaults to `undefined`.

You'd get the same results if you entered `;`.

To get an actual object, you need to make sure `{` is interpreted as part of an expression, not the beginning of a statement, for example by using `({})`.